# Question about the 'last seen' field

Tags: discussion

Does the 'last seen' field refer to a user's activity on a particular site, or across the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "last seen" field is judging when you were last seen for a particular site.

Example:

Looking at activity for Math SE

[image]

And for Meta

[image]

Taken at the same time, but you were last seen differently on each.

If you want me to change the pics for privacy reasons I can.

Answer (score 7):

This is on a particular site.

Just to  prove, here is [my profile on arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/7652/shadow-wizard):

> [image]

While here on MSE it is:

> [image]